# Android VideoView set video quality in live streaming

Tags: android

I can load a video from the web. All works fine.

However, when a network connection is slow the video is buffering. So I want to set the quality of video while, streaming it automatically or manually.

I am blank about this.

Comment: you can't just set a desired quality for a video since it sends a file (or a stream) over the network. Anyway it is a set of bytes in original quality. If you want to use lower quality, you have to store another file with lower quality on the server side, where you play video from.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, VideoView only plays the video. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is the documentation on it, doesn't seem to have that option at all.

I'd suggest you use the youtube API instead if you can.

Comment: Ok. Is there any alternate solution for streaming video online with quality

Comment: @BalaRaja are you using your own service? And is the user downloading the file and then playing it or is it progressive?